# MongoDB get specific fields between dates

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

For example I have an object like this

```
{
    id: string,
    createdAt: Date,
    createdBy: string,
    height: number,
    weight: number,
    fatPercentage: number,
    musclePercentage: number,
    shoulder: number,
    arm: number,
    forearm: number,
    chest: number,
}
```

How do I get only `fatPercentage` and `createdAt` values between a specific `createdAt` date in a MongoDB query?

Answer (score 3):

if your mongoose in version 5 :

```
Model.find({createdAt:{$gt:ISODate(startDate),$lt:ISODate(endDate)}).select('createdAt fatPercentage')
```

if version 6 :

```
Model.find({createdAt:{$gt:ISODate(startDate),$lt:ISODate(endDate)},'createdAt fatPercentage')
```

if mongo driver :

```
db.collection.find({createdAt:{$gt:ISODate(startDate),$lt:ISODate(endDate)},{createdAt:1, fatPercentage:1})
```